Recommendation System: Two-Tower Model Underperforming Simple Embedding Average Baseline
I'm trying to build a recommendation on a dataset of product purchases. The dataset consists of roughly 4 Amazon products that a particular user has bought (in sequence). I want to use the first 3 purchases to predict the next product the user will likely buy.
To get an initial baseline, I took a simple approach:

Used a text embedding model to generate an embedding for each product in the training set and indexed them in a vector DB.
In the test set, I averaged the interaction product embeddings and did a nearest neighbor search on that.
This gave me a recall@10 of 38.65%

I then proceeded to build a two-tower model with a frozen item tower. The user tower consists of a single linear layer that accepts the average interaction embeddings for each user as input and the loss function minimizes the cosine / dot product distance between the average embedding and the target item embedding.
user_embedding = mean(product_1_embed + product_2_embed + product_3_embed)
item_embedding = product_4_embed (target)

Evaluation is done by passing the average embeddings of a given user's purchases in the test set through the model, and then using the resulting vector to do a nearest neighbor search on the frozen item embeddings to locate products.
Problem: After training for a few epochs, the model is overfitting to the training data and metrics like recall is even lower than the simple average embedding baseline approach:
Recall@10 comparison

Baseline: 38.65%
With linear layer: 31.13%

Things that I tried that did not help:

adding a drop-out layer
using item tower also (instead of using frozen item embedding)
tweaking learning rate / batch size etc.
2 dense layers with RELU activation

Can someone help me understand why the model with linear adapter is not able to reach atleast the baseline approach's metrics?
Loss Curve

Model definition in PyTorch
class RecommendationModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, features, dropout_rate=0.4):
        super().__init__()
        self.user_network = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(features, features),
            nn.Dropout(dropout_rate),
        )

    def forward(self, user_inputs, item_inputs):
        ux = self.user_network(user_inputs)
        return ux, item_inputs

Training Configs

Training dataset size - 3508 Users and 15K products
Batch size - 877
Learning Rate - 3e-3
Warmup Ratio - 0.1
Scale (temprature) - 20.0

You can find the full code and how to run it. Link (Github Gist)
